# Converting numerical strings in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi using Snowflake I'm trying to take numbers such as 200k or 200M and convert them into 200000 and 2000000000.
I'm new to regex and using regex cheatsheet I was able create the regex string find numbers in that have k in them but I'm not able to replace the k part with 000's.

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('234k', '(^.*[Kk]$)','000')
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction or tell me how it is done?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do it with regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following expression:-

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(<column, or string>, '[Kk]$', '000'),'[Mm]$', '000000');
```

$ means the end of the string so will not replace unless the abbreviation is correct and at the end.

Testing:

```
//replace the k to 000 \
select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('15k', '[Kk]$', '000'),'[Mm]$', '000000');  
//replace the m to 000000 \
select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('15m', '[Kk]$', '000'),'[Mm]$', '000000'); 

//no replace \
select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('15k1', '[Kk]$', '000'),'[Mm]$', '000000'); 
select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('15m1', '[Kk]$', '000'),'[Mm]$', '000000');
```

**Note:** removed the \d* in my earlier answer as it is useless to use in the matching pattern and gives the same result.

Answer (score 1):

`'(^.*[Kk]$)'` matches to the whole string and so you replace the whole string with `000`.

Instead you should match `[Kk]` and replace it with `000`.

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('234k', '[Kk]', '000')
```

Notice that you don't really have to use regular expressions then, a normal function for replacing a substring would work too (I don't know Snowflake, but its docs suggest `REPLACE` function).

Comment: Thanks Alex, I used replace earlier and was able to get it to work but the problem was if data came in as 2K1 which is an error it'll misreport the value. So I was trying to replace K with 000 only if it is at the end of the string. I guess I could use case when with replace and regex.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like `replace()`:

```
  select replace(replace(lower(col), 'k', '000'), 'm', '000000')
```